# Select INTO range Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

I have recently been using ADO to move data between a database and Excel using ADO, this all works as expected, however, for the first time, the data isn't of a "standard"  format, where I have run information, file paths etc, input information, the arguments used and then the output, what's out after the macro in excel is run.  The purpose of the ADO is to say, I have a sheet HSBC_Stock_0% and I want to model it at 1.5% then everything would be the same, except the value of 1.5% in the run info, it would then create the new sheet as HSBC_Stock_1.5% ready for me to model next time I am in.

I have everything working as I'd like data wise, however, there is a 7 row company header that has to go in, so I'd like to do the SELECT INTO, but to a specific range, is this possible?

`strSQL = "Select * into [" & strNewTabName & "] FROM [Sheet1$]"`

is an example of how I am tacking the creation of the new tab, I'd like to create this in a10:b20 for example.  I am suspecting that the "table" from excel is required to not contain blank header cells.

Comment: I am guessing that the above line of code is part of a larger VBA macro which is designed to return a recordset. Afterwards, the result of the recordset is pasted to a sheet using the [CopyFromRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839240.aspx) (or something similar). If I am guessing correctly then you should change this line of code (where you are pasting the result) and not the query above.

Comment: @Ralph, no I am using ADO from o/s the workbook.  ADO is being used to stop having to open the full workbook each time

Comment: Not sure if `Jet OLE DB` supports "select into". Have you tried using the syntax proposed here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/278973 which would be something like `[newSheetName$A10:B20]` (of course the new sheet must exist already)?

Comment: Yes, I get the error This table contains cells that are outside the range of cells defined in this spreadsheet.  It supports with out the cell reference, but in A1

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with that (using SELECT INTO with closed Excel files). Hence, my suggestions are limited. The above referenced article (by Microsoft) suggests that it ought to be possible using their provided syntax. Did you have a look at this (somewhat strange) work-around to solve this problem: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-35680.html Maybe it can help. Other than that I hope someone else here can provide further insights.

Comment: That solution involves a named table or range, where as the select into is creating a new tab, so I don't have that, I have the longer option of using INSERT INTO from a table created using CREATE TABLE or just to query the empty range into a recordset then put the values into it and update, was just being hopeful, there would be a solution.  I tried to use some data with an empty column and it substituted F1 into its place, so think it has to have headers.  Unless anyone can help/confirm.  Thanks Ralph